# overloading streaming operator issues

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with printing via operator overloading.  Currently I am creating a database which contains an Item class as the base class, and the derived classes from Item are Movie, Book, and MusicAlbum.  Here is an example of how a book is inserted into the library:

```
Item    *item;

cout << ">>>>>> adding items to library:" << endl << endl;
item = library->addBook("The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time",  "Mark Haddon", 240);
if (item != NULL) {
    library->addKeywordsForItem(item, 2, "autism", "Asperger's Syndrome");
    cout << item << endl;
    }
```

Where addBook is a function defined in the class Library, as well as addKeywordsForItem.  My issue is the line:
cout << item << endl;

I understand that I need to  overload the streaming << operator in order to do this, but my main function (which is where the code above came from) includes similar functions for adding a movie and music album as well.  My function for overloading the streaming operator is located in my base class, and receives a base class pointer as a parameter, like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Item* item);
```

For Book, I need to print the title, author, number of pages, and it's keywords.  For movie and music album, there are specific things to print from those also.

How can I use only the one function in my base class that overloads the streaming operator, to print any of the information I need?  No matter whether the base class pointer is referring to an instance of Book, Movie, or MusicAlbum?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The overload of `operator<<` should be a free function, not a member of your base class.

Comment: The initialization of the pointer is in a part of the code we were instructed to not change, as well as where the operator overload function is.

Comment: @IanLindquist, My apologies. I saw everything except the `item =` part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The usual is to have a global overload that forwards to a virtual function:

```
struct Base {    
    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const { 
        return os << base_data;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {     
    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream *os) const { 
       return os << derived_data;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, base const &b) { 
    return b.print(os);
}
```

Each derived class will override `print` as needed to print itself onto a stream. Since the `operator<<` takes a `Base` by reference, it can use normal virtual dispatch to forward to the implementation of `print` in the correct class based on the dynamic type of the object it receives.

Comment: This helped out a ton and I think is going to solve my issue.  Thanks!